# benchmarks for register allocation in SSA-form

Tags: graph, benchmarking, ssa

i want to do graph coloring on chordal graphs. i need some chordal graphs and their results to compare my work against theme. can anyone help me?
for example

```
164.gzip    
175.vpr    
176.gcc      
181.mcf    
186.crafty    
197.parser    
252.eon
253.perlbmk    
254.gap    
255.vortex
256.bzip2    
300.twolf
```

That is a part of the CPU2000 benchmark suite.
It is source code for the individual benchmarks, plus precompiled binaries
for the tools to run the benchmarks and the tools source code for platforms for which there are no binaries provided. 
i want only its graph and one of theme is enough for me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understand the question. You want some other tool, which does register allocation in SSA-form to compare your implementation against it? Then use [cparser+libfirm](http://libfirm.org), which contains the register allocator of Hack, who invented register allocation in SSA-form.